# how can i get two custom Post type data & display ito one slider into wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In my sites two custom post type, one is advertiser & 2nd is events, I m display this two CPT display into one slider, not image only content.

2 CPT created in my project,
1)Advertiser 2)Reader
 I m getting this two CPT content into one slider

Comment: Please provide more appropriate question... with examples if you have

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// The Query
$queryslider= new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => array( 'Advertiser', 'Reader' ), ));
query_posts( $queryslider);

// The Loop
while ( $queryslider->have_posts() ) : $queryslider->the_post();
     echo '<li class="slide">';
        the_title();
        /* and other content what you want */
     echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Good luck! :)

Comment: No problem! :)  i hope that help you ;)

Comment: How can i add slider & slide one by one post

Comment: Hm..i can't understand your question, you think 2 post in one slide or you want one post is slider or? :)

Comment: Hi manoj, 2 different custom post type like 1 is advertiser & 2nd is reader, in slider 1st slider is display advertiser content & in 2nd display event,it's posiible it display slider 1 by 1.

Comment: first slide or first slider?
if first slide "code" on top will work fine :)
if slider you need 2 slider and 2 query :)